# about tcpdump option - Get IP and protocol name

Tags: tcpdump

i use tcpdump to get Data(Date, Time, sourceIP, destinaionIP, protocol, port)
but i use -n option

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n -c 30
```

then, i recived non-translated port number like this

```
12:33:06.885503 IP 123.45.6.78.22 > 12.34.56.78.56586: Flags [P.], seq 128:192, ack 1, win 487, length 64
```

i want IP(not hostname) and translated protocol like this

```
12:44:55.403958 IP 12.34.56.78.ssh > 12.34.56.79.56586: Flags [P.], seq 2689726444:2689726572, ack 2564341067, win 510, length 128
```

have any option?

Answer (score 1):

With tcpdump command, the -n option disables IP to hostname resolution. It does not affect how the ports are displayed. It is the -nn option that disables both hostname and port name resolution.

The /etc/services file is used by applications (including tcpdump) to translate human readable service names into port numbers when connecting to a machine across a network.

So add an entry for port 22 in /etc/services and it must show up in your tcpdump as well.